# Find equation of the plane that this $x=\frac{1+t}{1-t}, y=\frac{1}{1-t^2}, z=\frac{1}{1+t}$ curve lies

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

> Prove that all points of the given curve lie in one plane, and find
> the equation of that plane:
>
> $$x=\frac{1+t}{1-t}, y=\frac{1}{1-t^2},  z=\frac{1}{1+t}.$$

If the given curve lies in one plane, then

$$a\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)+b\left(\frac{1}{1-t^2}\right)+c\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)+d=0.$$

Solving this I get $2a=c,a=d,a=\frac{-b}{4}.$

How from this find equation of plane? Or maybe I did something wrong?

When putting values back into equation of plane I get

$$ax-4ay+2az+a=0.$$ Now, problem is I can't cancel $a$ here because first of all, I need to prove that such plane exists.

Comment: Assuming that your calculation are right equation of plane will be $aX-4aY+2aZ+a=0$ or $X-4Y+2Z+1=0$

Comment: @RKK please see my edit

Comment: I assumed that $ax+by+cz+d$ plane exists but what if it does not exist and $a=0$? It obviously exists because my book says find equation of plane but I don't know how show that it exists.

Comment: One way to show that is that  unit binormal vector has constant direction i.e. $\frac{r'×r''}{|r'×r''|}$ is independent of t .

Comment: Also i don't understand why you cant cancel a out . If you think about it what you did is you got a curve with a parameter t let r(t) then you took an arbitrary plane and find out there intersection . Then you used condition what if the intersection is independent of t then you get whole curve . Finally you got result and you get a curve and a result a=0 which when put in equation give 0=0 no problem there . And as for existance part of plane if the curve was not  planner then you couldn't have got such equation of plane at first place .

Comment: @RKK thanks for help

Comment: Is it $x = (1 +t)(1 - t) $ or $x =\dfrac{1 - t}{1 + t}$ ?

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea $\frac{1+t}{1-t}$

Comment: You can't cancel the a. but you can choose a value for a.  i.e. say $a = 1.$

Comment: Would it be OK to just do something that's semi by inspection, such as: $x = -1 + \frac{2}{1-t}$, and so $y = \frac{1}{1-t^2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{1+t} + \frac{1}{1-t} \right) = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{2} (x+1) + z) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} x + \frac{1}{2} z$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the added value of using  the cross product in the alternative. To prove that the curve lies in a plane with normal vector $\hat{n} = (a,b,c)$  it is sufficient that the tangent vector $\hat{\tau} = (x,_t, y,_t,z,_t) $ of the curve is perpendicular to $\hat{n}$ for $ \forall  \ t \ \epsilon \ \mathbb{R}_{\setminus \{-1,1\}}$ .
So,
\begin{align}
\hat{\tau} &= (x,_t, y,_t,z,_t) \\
&= \left(\frac{2}{(1-t)^2}, \frac{2t}{(1-t^2)^2}, -\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\right)\\
\left\langle \hat{n} ,\hat{\tau}\right\rangle &= 0\\
&= a\frac{2}{(1-t)^2}+b\frac{2t}{(1-t^2)^2}-c\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\\
&= 2a(1+t)^2+ 2bt -c(1-t)^2 \\
 &= 0\\
\text{for }& \quad t=0 \ : \quad 2a-c = 0\\
\Rightarrow a = 1 \quad &\wedge\quad  c= 2 \quad \text{(we don't care about the size of the normal vector)}
\end{align}
On the condition that $t\neq 0$ we get
\begin{align}
b &= -\frac{(1+t)^2 - (1-t)^2}{t}\\
&= -4
\end{align}
With this, the existence of a plane is proved. And to determine the displacement of the plane we just have to solve
$$x-4y+2z + d =0$$
for any allowed value of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following parameteric curve

$x(t) = \dfrac{1 + t}{1 - t} , y(t) = \dfrac{1}{1 - t^2} , z(t) = \dfrac{1}{1 + t} $

As the OP pointed out, we can simply assume that the curve lies on the plane

$$ a x + b y + c z + d = 0 $$

And then try and find $a,b,c,d$.  Using this method, and multiplying through by  $(1 - t^2) $ results in

$ a (1 + t)^2 + b + c (1 - t) + d (1 - t^2) = 0 $

Collecting terms containing $t^2 , t $ and the constant terms we get

$ t^2 ( a - d ) + t ( 2 a - c ) + ( a + b + c + d) = 0 $

Taking $d = 1 $ , then

$ a = 1, c = 2 , b = -4 $

Thus this curve does indeed lie on the plane

$ x - 4 y + 2 z + 1 = 0 $

which has been pointed out by @RKK

A more involved method that is not necessarily better, is to differentiate $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ to obtain

$T(t) = (x'(t), y'(t), z'(t) ) = \left( \dfrac{ 2 }{(1 - t)^2 }, \dfrac{2 t}{(1 - t^2)^2} , -\dfrac{1}{(1 + t)^2 } \right) $

And then differentiate $T(t)$ to obtain

$T'(t) = ( \dfrac{ 4 }{ (1 - t)^3 } , \dfrac{ 2  + 6 t^2 }{ (1 - t^2)^3 } , \dfrac{ 2 }{(1 + t)^3 }) $

Now, we find the cross product $T(t) \times T'(t) $

$ T(t) \times T'(t) = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} && \mathbf{j} && \mathbf{k} \\
 \dfrac{ 2 }{(1 - t)^2 } && \dfrac{2 t}{(1 - t^2)^2} && -\dfrac{1}{(1 + t)^2 } \\
 \dfrac{ 4 }{ (1 - t)^3 } && \dfrac{ 2  + 6 t^2 }{ (1 - t^2)^3 } && \dfrac{ 2 }{(1 + t)^3 } \end{vmatrix} $

$ = \mathbf{i} \left( \dfrac{ 4 t }{ (1 - t^2)^2 (1 + t)^3 } + \dfrac{ 2 + 6 t^2 }{ (1 + t)^2 (1 - t^2)^3 } \right) \\
 + \mathbf{j} \left( - \dfrac{4}{ (1 + t)^2 (1 - t)^3 } - \dfrac{4}{(1 - t)^2 (1 + t)^3 } \right)
+ \mathbf{k} \left(  \dfrac{ 2 (2 + 6 t^2)}{(1 - t)^2 (1 - t^2)^3 } - \dfrac{ 8t }{ (1 - t)^3 (1 - t^2)^2} \right) $

And this simplifies to,

$ =\dfrac{2}{(1 - t^2)^3}  \left( \mathbf{i}  - 4 \mathbf{j} + 2 \mathbf{k} \right) $

Hence the vector $(1, -4, 2) $ is always normal to the curve, which means the curve lies in the plane $ x - 4 y + 2 z + d = 0 $

To find $d$ , substitute $t = 0$, you get the point $(1, 1, 1) $ on the plane, hence

$ d = - (1 - 4 + 2) = 1 $

Finally the equation of the plane is  $ x - 4 y + 2 z + 1 = 0 $

But the method of the OP and @RKK is much simpler than the second method that involved the tangent vector and its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

$\vec r_0:= (x(0),y(0),z(0))=(1,1,1);$

Equation of a plane passing through $\vec r_0,$ where  $\vec n:=(a, b, c)$ is the normal of the plane:

$\vec n \cdot (\vec r - \vec r_0)=$

$(a,b,c)\cdot (x-1,y-1,z-1)=$

$a(x-1)+b(y-1)+c(z-1)=0;$

If the curve lies in the plane then

$\vec r(t) =(x(t), y(t), z(t)) $ satisfies this equation for $t\not =\pm1$.

$ax(t) +by(t)+cz(t)=$

$a+b+c;$

$a(1+t)^2+b+c(1-t)=$

$(a+b+c)(1-t^2);$

A quadratic equation in $t$.

It is satisfied for all $t$ if the coefficients of $t^2,t$ and the constant are zero, which gives $3$ equations for $a, b, c.$

Assuming the system of equations is consistent and has one solution the curve lies in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that (for $t\neq\pm1$)
$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{2}{1-t}-1\iff\frac{1/2}{1-t}=\frac{x+1}{4},\\
y&=\frac{1/2}{1-t}-\frac{1/2}{1+t},\\
z&=\frac{1}{1+t}\iff\frac{1/2}{1+t}=\frac{z}{2}.
\end{align}$$
From here
$$y=\frac14(x+1)-\frac12z\iff x-4y+2z=-1.$$

Alternatively, the curves equation is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 0\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}+
\frac{1}{1-t}
\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 1/2 \\0
\end{pmatrix}+
\frac{1}{1+t}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\-1/2\\1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
clearly an equation of a part of a plane.